# Domain expired, GoDaddy holds it and is asking more money

Tags: domains, godaddy, expired-domains

After expiring my domain, GoDaddy is asking more money to renew. Why is GoDaddy holding my domain? If it expired it has to be open to buy right?

[image]

Answer (score 26):

In gTLD world, such as .COM it goes around like that:

- when a domain hits its expiration date, the registry auto-renews it
- this opens a 45 days period where the registrar can decide either to do nothing (then the domain gets really renewed past the 45 days delay, which means the registrar has been payed by its client to renew it), or delete the domain name (because the client decided not to renew it)
- when a domain name is deleted it is not immediately available again (except if it was deleted in a 5 days period after its creation, which is not our case here), it goes into a "redemption period"
- this was created to be able to undo unwanted deletion
- hence registrar, upon order from their client, can restore the domain name to put it back out of the redemption and working again
- but because this is an extreme last measure actions, registry put a specific price on the restore operation that it far more than a standard create/renew/transfer, and of course this fee is also pushed by the registrar to its client

You can visualize all of this on this ICANN diagram:

[image: gTLD domain lifecycle by ICANN]

Depending on when the registrar decides to delete it, you may have to wait up to 45+30+5=80 days before the domain name becomes available to register by anyone (first come first served). But if you value your domain it is a bad idea to go this route for at least 2 reasons:

1. at some point during the delay  above your domain may stop to work correctly as not resolving anymore; this can surely impact your operations
2. once really fully deleted and available to anyone you have absolutely no guarantee to be the first to get it, hence you may loose it definitively once for all.

If you have a problem with you current registrar you should still renew the domain (as it is far too late now) properly, then wait typically 60 days, then do the transfer to any other registrar to your liking. Absolutely wait 60 days between renewal and transfer otherwise you will pay twice but your domain will be extended only by one year for reasons too long to explain here.

But based on your whois output, the domain seems to have been already really renewed by the registrar, because otherwise it would have been in the "autoRenewPeriod", see https://icann.org/epp. So you do not seem to be anymore in the above case of expiration handling.

Except that your registrar whois shows:

```
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2019-03-17T07:29:51Z
```

(which is different from registry expiration date for the reasons given above)
which is contradictory.
You may need to contact it directly to clear out the situation.

> Why godaddy holding my domain ? If it expired it has to be open to buy right?

Did you read the contract between you and GoDaddy precisely? Your rights on the domain may as well have ended as soon as the expiration was hit.
Which, as explained above, does not mean it becomes immediately available again for registration.

Comment: Actually, it's *much, much worse* when the registrar does not shut down DNS service on the domain during the redemption grace period.  Because then you do not get the early warning of your site going down, and can be blindsided when the domain fully expires, and it will get snatched up by a prospector before you know it.  Exactly this happened to an organization I work with, and it was GoDaddy, and I wonder if someone at GoDaddy prevented the domain from crashing during the redemption period and was working in cahoots with the prospector.

Comment: @Harper some registrars may do it, some may don't. Because typically they would have already sent more than one email to warn about the expiration (it is completely in the interest of the registrar to have the customer renew it, the sooner the better). But you are right, and based on personal previous experiences, whatever number of emails you sent some people will start to realize they need to act only when the domain name ceases to work at all, which a registrar can do by using the `clientHold` status, shortly after expiration.

Comment: The problem is, this "Send email to the customer" method of notifying domain renewals doesn't always work for a variety of reasons, and this is too important to hang it all on 1 method of contact.

Comment: @Harper also there are various online services or software tools to monitor domain names (besides your registrars) that are useful. Big companies should in general take more care of the DNS and their domains as there are true assets for which they often do not spend the same amount of money they spend for webhosting or CDNs... all that stuff that is moot if the domain names does not work anymore or is sold to someone else.

Comment: @Harper "The problem is, this "Send email to the customer" method of notifying domain renewals doesn't always work for a variety of reasons, and this is too important to hang it all on 1 method of contact." Agreed but like I said there are other services, you just need to shop around. For example with some registrars you can have a prepaid balance hence giving money upfront and say if the domain is to be autorenewed or dropped at expiration. Then everything happens automatically. Or provide with a credit card number that can be used without customer action.

Comment: @Harper, also domains, typically in gTLDs, can be registered for 10 years in advance. Prices do change, but more often they increase. Hence I see few reasons, for valuable domain names, not to register them immediately for 10 years. You have then at least 10 years to start worrying about the renewal (probably earlier if you get problems with the registrar or just wish to transfer it elsewhere to consolidate your portfolio for example). Look at big players' domain names, and the expiration date, it is rarely in one year in the future only.

Comment: Yeah I know, that was one more link in the failure chain.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica About "Actually, it's much, much worse when the registrar does not shut down DNS service on the domain during the redemption grace period." note that there is an ICANN regulation on this (but hence only for gTLD), see https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/errp-2013-02-28-en and §2.2: "For registrations deleted within eight days of expiration: The existing DNS resolution path specified by the RAE must be interrupted by the registrar from expiration of the registration until its deletion, to the extent the applicable registry permits such interruptions."

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

Find GoDaddy Expired Domain Renewal Cycle Here:
https://in.godaddy.com/help/renewing-my-expired-domain-name-609

NEVER POST SUCH SENSITIVE DOMAIN INFORMATION IN PUBLIC.

As, you are already in Redemption Period, Easiest way according to me is Buy Domain from Go Daddy Expired Domain Auction.

You will get your domain for a cheaper rate than the Redemption Fees. And if possible remove this domain info ASAP from public attention.

They will not hold your domain for long, if they failed to sell it in Auction then they will release it as per the Lifecycle.

PRO TIP: Use "Buy Now" option at Auction / Bid at very last day / hour / minutes before Auction expiry to avoid unnecessary attention.

Comment: "As, you are already in Redemption Period,"  where do you see that?

Comment: Why not?  The data is readily available from WHOIS.  There is no security through obscurity; many prospectors scrape WHOIS data looking for domains about to pop; they run site metrics on them to see if they are worth stealing, and 1 second after they come available they scrum to re-register them, either for extortion-back, or to monetize traffic or PageRank.  All automatic.  They know of every domain because they pull master DNS records.  You can't hide from this.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Please check the GoDaddy's link posted in my Post. There is an expiration timeline, which shows on the 19th day after expiration, domain enters into Redemption Period.

Comment: @Harper Yes, you are right there isn't any security and Data is available in Public. But this way, Publishing a domain in Public doesn't make any sense. It will get unnecessary attention. For example, the Drop Catch process you explained here (re-register in 1 second), the process of buying from auction suggested by me, etc. are known to many users. If anyone comes to this question and find out this domain valuable he will try to get some profit. And the owner will suffer. Web Crawler also does their job in this kind of situation. Domain Thieves will get easy targets.

Comment: yes but "redemption" has a specific meaning in the domain name industry, this happens only after deletion, which based on your very own link happens only 42 days after expiration at GoDaddy... it is just **sujected** to redemption fee, this is only a business decision of the registrar, it is not deleted nor in redemption...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek After Deletion nothing happens, After Deletion it will be available in Open Market for re-registration. Check the life cycle posted by you.
In GoDaddy's link posted by me, Redemption period is mentioned in point no.2  i.e. Day 19. And after 42nd Day it will be available for re-registration not redemption.

Comment: "After Deletion nothing happens," this is not true, see the domain name lifecycle. You are speaking about a specific case at a specific registrar. I am trying to give generic answers that applies everywhere. Any deletion in gTLDs, except during the 5 days period after creation, creates a redemption period.

Comment: Talking Generic, After Expiration of the Domain it goes to Auto Renew Period, then Redemption Period aka "Pending Delete - Restore able"  in this period one can pay the redemption fees and save the Domain, Then it will go for final deletion, no one can restore that domain for that 5 days span and as soon as it gets deleted after 5 days, it will immediately available for registration to anyone. No any periods / barriers.