# Godaddy holding domain after expired

Tags: domains, godaddy

This domain expired on 2020-05-30, [image: see the screenshot]

Godaddy says after 40 days the domain gets back to the registrar for anyone buy

Yesterday, it already was parked for deletion

I waited for this time to acquire the domain,

But today, for my surprise, it was automatically renewed by Godaddy, see 2021-05-30,

as if they were the owners of the domain.

How is this possible ? What do id do to get the domain ?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post images. Copy paste the relevant text.

Comment: "see 2021-05-30," No, this is the REGISTRY expiration date, this gets automatically incremented (in gTLD like in your `.com`)  by one year on the expiration date.

Comment: Should be relevant: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122104/domain-expired-godaddy-holds-it-and-is-asking-more-money

Comment: Just an advice. Rather than waiting for it to become available. Try to search GoDaddy Market and place a backorder on it. If it is goes into aftermarket and if someone bids on it then it will never be available for regular registration until once again that person allows it to drop completely.